# Set MySql read-only from K8s cluster

Tags: mysql, read-only-database

I have a Kubernetes cluster running with MySQL app (5.7.32 MySQL version). I'm trying to make MySQL app be in a consistency mode, using this command:

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON;
```

When I run this command from **inside the app - it works** (getting error when trying to write when the DB is locked):

```
kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql

mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON; INSERT INTO mydb.mytable VALUES('hello');
```

But When I run this command using **`kubectl exec` command - it doesn't work** (this command doesn't fail, and it is able to write to the DB):

```
kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql -h mysql \
-e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON; INSERT INTO mydb.mytable VALUES('hello'); "
```

I also try using a **grant privileged user**, it didn't help:

```
kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql -h mysql \
-e "CREATE USER $USER@'$HOST' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASS'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO $USER@'$HOST';"

kubectl exec -ti mysql-0 -c mysql -- mysql -h mysql -u $USER -p$PASS \
-e "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; SET_GLOBAL read_only = ON; INSERT INTO mydb.mytable VALUES('hello'); "
```

How can I bring my MySQL app to be in a read-only state without running the command from inside the application?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `SUPER` privilege allows the user to write to a read_only server.

Do *NOT* use such a user for anything other than admin purposes.  Use less-privileged user(s) for application actions.  Usually, an "app" user should be granted only `... ON dbname.* ...`.